# Why wont the border on this input element change back?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using regex to confirm a valid email is entered. It works great, and when the email is incorrect, the border is red, when the email is correct the border goes back to normal. BUT if I delete the email after entering it, the border STAYS red. I can't figure out why this is happening?

```js
const emailInput = document.querySelector("#email");

emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const emailInputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  if( /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailInputValue) != true) {
      emailInput.style.border = "thin solid red";
  } else {
      emailInput.style.border = "";
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="email" class="required">Email:</label>
<div id="email_div">
    <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50">
    <label for="email" id="email_text">This field is required in order to receive an email confirmation.</label>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test for empties:

```
if(emailInputValue.trim() !=='' &&  ...
```

in your code

```
emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const emailInputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  if(emailInputValue.trim() !=='' &&  /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailInputValue) != true) {
      emailInput.style.border = "thin solid red";
  } else {
      emailInput.style.border = "";
  }
})
```

I prefer to use classes for this kind of thing. It's more flexible and adheres to best practices:

```js
const emailInput = document.querySelector("#email");
emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const emailInputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  let valid = emailInputValue.trim() === '' || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailInputValue);
  if (!valid) emailInput.classList.add('invalid');
  else emailInput.classList.remove('invalid');
})
```

```css
input{
padding:5px;
}
.invalid {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  background: rgb(249,241,241);
}
```

```html
<label for="email" class="required">Email:</label>
<div id="email_div">
  <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50">
  <label for="email" id="email_text">This field is required in order to receive an email confirmation.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are deleting the content of input field, `input` event is fired and empty string is checked against your regex which is returning true. that's why border stays the red.

I have added the check, if input value is empty string then reset the border color

```js
const emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');

emailInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const emailInputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
   if(emailInputValue.trim()===""){
    emailInput.style.border = '';
    return;
  }
  if (
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailInputValue) !=
    true
  ) {
    emailInput.style.border = 'thin solid red';
    emailInput.style.outline = 'none';
  } else {
    emailInput.style.border = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="email" class="required">Email:</label>
<div id="email_div">
  <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50">
  <label for="email" id="email_text">This field is required in order to receive an email confirmation.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing easier.

Just add a new arg into `if`. Maybe something like this:

```
  if (
    !/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailInputValue) &&
    emailInputValue.trim() !== ""
  ) {
```

full code:

```js
const emailInput = document.querySelector("#email");

emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const emailInputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  const emailTest = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(
    emailInputValue
  );
  
  if (!emailTest && emailInputValue.trim() !== "") {
    emailInput.style.border = "thin solid red";
  } else {
    emailInput.style.border = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="email" class="required">Email:</label>
<div id="email_div">
  <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50">
  <label for="email" id="email_text">This field is required in order to receive an email confirmation</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the styling every time it is empty. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/eYWYOLx)

```
const emailInput = document.querySelector("#email");

emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const emailInputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  if(emailInputValue == ''){
    emailInput.style.border = "thin solid red";
  }
  else{
    
  if(  /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailInputValue) != true) {
      emailInput.style.border = "thin solid red";
  } else {
      emailInput.style.border = "";
  }
  }
})
```